# IE убирает границы ячеек при печати нескольких страниц

Tags: php, html, css, вёрстка, phpexcel

При попытке распечатать таблицу, сгенерированную через *phpExcel*, *IE* игнорирует любые стили и границы, при переходе на следующую страницу.

При выводе в браузер - все отображается корректно, а при печати - уже нет.

`border-collapse`, ручное прописывание стилей ячейкам, использование @media print css, и прочее не помогло.

Стили на второй странице выборочно игнорируются, при попытке печатать.

p.s. Прошу прощения за такой способ делания скриншотов. На виндовом компе нет интернета и возможности вставить флешку.

В браузере:

[image: Отображение нижней половины таблицы в браузере]

В предварительном просмотре:

[image: Она же, при попытке распечатать]

[Пример сгенерированного проблемного кода.](http://pastebin.com/gcamtNS2)

Решение из [соседней темы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750134/ie-10-missing-border-segments-while-printing-table-elements) не сработало - там другая проблема была.

Вариант с перемещением `doctype` в самое начало кода не сработал.

На данный момент воспроизвелось на всех актуальных версиях IE.
На Edge не воспроизвелось, он уже на другом движке.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <title>Печать технологической карты обслуживания и ремонта для ЕО "Экземпляр №3 мерный"</title><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> ```

`title` не должен стоять до `doctype`. Такое размещение тегов приводит к переходу в режим Quirks 5 (эмуляции IE 5.5), в котором не только почти все возможности css не поддерживаются, но и имеется огромное количество всяческих багов.

Скорее всего, перенос доктайпа в начало документа решит проблему со стилями.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KgKpgQ7V Вот вариант кода с доктайпом в начале. К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков, пустую строку тоже убрать. Убрать всё, даже BOM. Т. е. символ `<` должен быть первым в документе.

Comment: Некорректно вставил в pastebin. В коде вот так http://pastebin.com/gcamtNS2

Comment: @ВикторЖариков, действительно не помогает... Дело явно в куче правил с important'ами - при их убирании что-то меняется.

Comment: К сожалению данный код автогенерится в phpExcel. Поэтому поменять я его могу тоже только средствами данной библиотеки. Какие important вы убрали для достижения нужного эффекта? Попробую покопать в этом направлении.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков, я снял галоски с границ для 7 и 8 стилей и у меня отрисовались ещё куски границ, которых до этого не было.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44992/discussion-between---and-qwertiy).

Comment: Не появилось ли у вас новых идей?